# force Octave to show only scientific notation

Tags: octave, notation

See this code below, from Octave's Command Prompt:

```
>> log( 0.1 ) * 5e-8
 ans = -0.00000011513
```

As can be seen, there are quite a few zeros ( 6 to be exact). I would like if the number is displayed as 1.1513e-7. Or, scientific notation, by default. How does one do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the format of the ouput displayed by octave with the function [`format`](https://octave.org/doc/v4.0.1/Terminal-Output.html),

e.g. `format short e` forces short length exponential notation, which seems that is what you want.